# Select highest ranked group only

Tags: php, mysql

So im trying to make a integration between my XenForo forum and Source Mod (Counter Strike mod).
XenForo saves the user groups a member is a member of like this.

| user_id | user_group_id | is_primary |

That means some members is in that table more then 1 time, in the result I want to have one row of every member max and it should containt the users highest ranked group.

Im not very experienced with this kind of sql queries so I would be glad if someone could help me with this.

The groups i want to have in the result is 5-12, 5 is highest ranked and 12 is lowest ranked. All other groups should not be in the result.

A few rows from the table

```
user_id | user_group_id | is_primary
1 | 2 | 1
1 | 3 | 0
1 | 4 | 0
1 | 5 | 0
2 | 2 | 1
2 | 5 | 0
3 | 2 | 1
4 | 2 | 1
4 | 6 | 0
```

**EDIT:** The result I want would look like this If the table only contained the rows above.

```
user_id | user_group_id
1 | 5
2 | 5
4 | 6
```

Best regards

Comment: You need to provide information about the table where the groups are ranked.

Comment: i don't get what record out of your table you want to get. Edit your answer and make a second table with the result you want

Comment: @phant0m Thats what I did. If you would look at the code block theres four members in it.
@yes123 Done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typing this off the top, but it should do the job:

```
SELECT user_id, ΜΙΝ(user_group_id) AS min_group_id
FROM users
WHERE user_group_id >= 5 && user_group_id <= 12
GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: @Jon: Shouldn't it be `MIN(user_group_id) AS highest_group_id` ?

Comment: Yeah It should be. I changed MAX to MIN in my query.

Comment: @ypercube: Yeah, my mistake. Fixed it for posterity.

Answer (score 1):

```
select user_id, min(user_group_id)
from xf_user_group_relation
where max_group_id between 5 and 12
group by user_id
```

Comment: @BlackVoid Your question was not very clear at first sight for me. So corrected! :) But I see that @Jon was first who understood you better.